# How to pass values to pyspark variable from a table?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This might be a silly question but I have a table with each column containing a value that I want to pass to a variable:

```py
    object  = spark.sql("""
     select sfObject from db.tbl
     where Id = {}
      """.format(1))
    
    a.show()
```

What I see is a column called `sfObject` with its expected corresponding value 'ValueA' and I get back a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` type object.

I'm trying to pass the values from each column to a variable such that `object = 'ValueA'`. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want the value of the column instead of the dataframe, so in your case you can do something like this

```py
object  = spark.sql("""
 select sfObject from db.tbl
 where Id = {}
  """.format(1)).collect()[0][0]
```

The object will now contain the value instead of the dataframe.

Comment: if I were to run type(object) i'd get back a string type. How can I modify this so I get back a date type? thank you!

Comment: You need to cast the column to date type

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to get the data from DataFrame in your python shell as a variable. For that you can either use

```
object.collect()
```

to get a list of `pyspark.sql.Row` python objects with fields corresponding to columns in the DataFrame, or

```
object.toPandas()
```

to get a pandas `DataFrame` object with the data.